# Compile terraform locally?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terraform

im having a lot of issues with file paths for modules being wrong and etc... and I can't run my script locally because of security concerns so I have to commit the changes, push, run CI, start CD and get approvals for CD...

Is there a way to compile my terraform to check if everything fits? Something that would tell me "Hey, you said that source for `moduleW` is at `./ApplicationModules/Databases/moduleW.tf` but I can't find that file there!"

Im currently using VSCode and I already have terraform-by-microsoft and terraform-by-hashicorp

**Edit 1**
here is a sample.
File Structure:

```
/main.tf  
/variables.tf
/ResourceGroupRoles/Custom-Dev-RoleDefinition.tf
/ResourceGroupRoles/Custom-FinOpsOperator-RoleDefinition.tf
```

main.tf:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

module "dev-role-def" {
  source = "./ResourceGroupRoles/Custom-Dev-RoleDefinition.tf"
}

module "finOps-role-def" {
  source = "./ResourceGroupRoles/Custom-FinOpsOperator-RoleDefinition.tf"
}
```

Custom-Dev-RoleDefinition.tf:

```
resource "azurerm_role_definition" "dev-role-def" {
  name        = "Application Developer"
  scope       = var.subscription_scope
  description = "Custom base role for application developers"

  permissions {
    actions = [
      ......... bunch of stuff .........
    ]

    not_actions = [
      ...... bunch of other stuff .......
    ]
  }

  assignable_scopes = [var.subscription_scope] 
}
```

Custom-FinOpsOperator-RoleDefinition.tf

```
similar to previous one, but other roles
```

Current errors:

```
The directory ResourceGroupRoles/Custom-Dev-RoleDefinition.tf could not be read for module "dev-role-def" at main.tf:5

The directory ResourceGroupRoles/Custom-FinOpsOperator-RoleDefinition.tf could not be read for module "finOps-role-def"
```

Note: if I copy the modules back to main.tf, removing the module referencing, it works

Comment: Some code would be nice... it all depends on how complex is that code, what providers and resources it is using, any other dependencies that are not available outside the CI/CD.

Comment: What are these security concerns that you can't run a terraform plan locally?

Comment: @HelderSepulveda its called enterprise governance... Please check edit1 for code sample

Comment: Sorry, just saying enterprise governance is as vague as security concerns. I've worked on a highly secure companies and on all We (DevOps engineers) are able to run Terraform plans locally against a test environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are allowed to run a `terraform init`, then you could run a `terrraform validate` to have a first layer of checks done (docs [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/validate)).

Also, I often run a `terraform console` command (docs [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/console)) that allows you a deeper validation, but it acquires the lock on the state file, so if you cannot plan locally, you probably cannot run that locally either, but it is worth trying.

Anyway, in your code example, you are referencing modules incorrectly, since you cannot put a .tf file as a source, but only directories.

Thus, since `Custom-Dev-RoleDefinition.tf` and `Custom-FinOpsOperator-RoleDefinition.tf` are placed in the same directory (`ResourceGroupRoles`) Terraform considers them to be part of the same module (`source = "./ResourceGroupRoles"` would be the correct way of sourcing the module).

If you need them to be part of two distinct modules, you must place them in two different directories.

As a good practice, you should place all of your modules in the `modules` directory, thus you may want your hierarchy to look like the following:

```
/main.tf  
/variables.tf
/modules/CustomDevRoleDefinitions/Custom-Dev-RoleDefinition.tf
/modules/CustomFinOpsOperator/Custom-FinOpsOperator-RoleDefinition.tf
```

Comment: Running `terraform init -backend=false` before running `terraform validate` can sometimes be helpful in environments where the remote state is not reachable from developer workstations. `terraform validate` is a configuration-only command -- it doesn't use the prior state at all -- so unlike most Terraform commands it can work with an uninitialized backend as long as all of the required modules and providers are installed.